GPIO.setup(BOARD.LED, GPIO.OUT)
I want to send a message using LoRa SX1278 using raspberry pi 4 as a receiver and LoRa SX1278 with raspberry pi 5 as its transmitter. we have downloaded git clone from the following link: https://github.com/rpsreal/pySX127x
code:
import sys
from time import sleep
from SX127x.LoRa import *
from SX127x.board_config import BOARD
# import the python libraries
BOARD.setup()
# is used to set the board and LoRa parameters
class LoRaBeacon(LoRa):

    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(LoRaBeacon, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        # sleep to save power
        self.set_dio_mapping([1,0,0,0,0,0])
        #go to this web to read the doc: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/3179/sx1276_77_78_79.pdf
    def start(self):
        global args
        self.write_payload([])
        self.set_mode(MODE.TX)
        while True:
              sleep(1)
    def on_tx_done(self):
        self.set_mode(MODE.STDBY)
        self.clear_irq_flags(TxDone=1)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(2)
        data=input('>>> ')
        a=[int(hex(ord(m)), 0) for m in data]
        #set format array data in 1 byte 
        print(a)
        self.write_payload(a)
        self.set_mode(MODE.TX)

lora = LoRaBeacon(verbose=False)

lora.set_pa_config(pa_select=1)

assert(lora.get_agc_auto_on() == 1)

try: sleep(0.001)
except: pass

try:
    lora.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stderr.write("KeyboardInterrupt\n")
 #print the transmitted values on the console and terminate the program using a keyboard interrupt   
finally:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    lora.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
    BOARD.teardown()

but it shows the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bbnasution/lora_send.py", line 6, in <module>
BOARD.setup()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyLoRa-0.3.1-py3.11.egg/SX127x/board_config.py", line 61, in setup 
GPIO.setup(BOARD.LED, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: Cannot determine SOC peripheral base address

even though I have disabled the command on line 61.
please help me

The LoRa module is using the RPi.GPIO module.
The RPi.GPIO module does not work on the Pi5.
